# Unwanted line elements in Forge/B360 Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elglB.jpg)

We have a graphical issue with a ifc model in BIM 360.
When uploaded, it contains additional line elements, as seen in the screenshot.

Our client who provided us with the model says that he sees the same line elements in Navisworks.
They contacted Autodesk Support and they told them that Forge/B360 uses the same Revit IFC Engine for the import.

We don't want these lines visible in BIM 360/Forge Viewer.
Is this a known issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As those lines are also visible in Navisworks, then those are likely part of the model. That said, you can: (1) change the original model to hide those elements on the view or (2) make the viewer hide those elements, but that requires you to filter those elements (e.g. hide all elements matching a specific attribute value).

Is this something that could work on your scenario?